# ¿Comó eliminar objecto anidacion de un Json en javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Me encuntro con este problema de este Json porque no necesito que no este anidado ya que se  me dificual para hacer una funcionalidad, que quiero en mi aplicacion este es un ejemplo de como tengo el Json actualmente.

Tengo este **JSON**

```
"content": [
        {
            "id": {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02- 
            28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }

]
```

como puede conseguir un **Json** sin anidacion como este

```
"content": [
        {
           
            "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
            "idCliente": 830065063,
           
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02- 
            28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario complicarse tanto creando una clase, puedes simplemente usar [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = {"content": [
        {
            "id": {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }

]};
Object.entries(obj.content[0].id).map(el => obj["content"][0][el[0]] = el[1]);
delete obj.content[0].id;
console.log(obj);
```

Después de insertar cada elemento de `id` en el objeto, usamos [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) para eliminar el índice `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Hazlo con [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), así:

```js
jsonObj = {"content": [
        {
            "id": {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }

]}

jsonObj.content.map(function(x) {
  x.fechaSolicitud = x.id.fechaSolicitud
  x.idCliente = x.id.idCliente
  delete x.id
  return x;
});

console.log(jsonObj);
```

**Explicación:**

Creamos un objeto denominado `jsonObj` con el **json** que nos has propocionado.

Con `map` estamos recorriendo cada objeto de su array `content` y le asignamos las nuevas propiedades y eliminamos la propiedad `id` existente después.

Finalmente lo mostramos en consola.

Comment: Puedes ahorrarte el `JSON.stringify` en la última línea e imprimir directamente el objeto

Comment: Es por si acaso, pues pide `como puede conseguir un Json sin anidacion`, y un objeto no es un json que yo entienda como tal, no se, tampoco soy un experto, pero diria que no es lo mismo... aunque veo que ambos pasan la validacion en https://jsonlint.com/... bueno, que decida el lo que quiere, tampoco está de más supongo

Comment: En realidad un JSON es un objeto. Con `JSON.stringify` lo estas convirtiendo en un string, si bien es cierto que los JSON con los que solemos trabajar suelen venirnos como strings y necesitamos convertirlos a objetos para poder trabajar con ellos, con `JSON.parse`. A efectos de mostrar un JSON en consola no sería necesario realizar ninguna conversión.

Comment: Tambien lo hacia para ver las comillas, tal como el lo pedia en la pregunta, por si acaso :-D ... pero seguro que tienes razón, venga, voy a cambiarlo, gracias por el aporte... vaya, pues tambien salen... que raro, en jsfidle creo que no salian, en fin, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La manera mas sencilla y en una sola línea es usar destructuracion:

```
jsonObj.content = jsonObj.content.map(({id, ...obj}) => ({...obj, ...id}));
```

**PRUEBA**

```js
jsonObj = {"content": [
        {
            "id": {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }

]};

jsonObj.content = jsonObj.content.map(({id, ...obj}) => ({...obj, ...id}));
console.log(jsonObj);
```

**EXPLICACION:**

Con `jsonObj.content.map` lo que estamos haciendo es recorrer cada uno de los elementos del array.

Con `({id, ...obj}) => {}` lo que estamos haciendo es una funcion que recibe cada uno de los elementos, y en ese mismo momento destructuramos ese elemento y separamos el `id` del resto de las propiedades (las cuales almacenamos en `obj`

Con  `=> ({...obj, ...id})` Le estamos indicando a la funcion que devuelva un objeto que estará compuesto por todas las propiedades de obj (sin el id) y por todas las propiedades internas de `id`

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    const jsonObj = {"content": [
        {
            "id": {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
            "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            "enviado": true,
            "pdf": true,
            "excel": true
        }
    ]};

    // Imprimir en consola el JSON original
    console.log(jsonObj.content[0]);

    const jsonData = jsonObj.content[0].id;
    // Imprimir en consola el contenido anidado:
    console.log(jsonData);

    // Añadir al JSON principal el contenido anidado en "id"
    Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log('Añadiendo: ' + key);

        jsonObj.content[0][key] = jsonObj.content[0].id[key];
    });

    // Imprimir en consola el JSON modificado
    console.log(jsonObj.content[0]);

    // Remover el contenido anidado del JSON modificado:
    delete jsonObj.content[0].id;

    // Imprimir JSON resultante
    console.log(jsonObj.content[0]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Paso por paso...

Primero guardas en una variable el contenido anidado cuyos pares clave valor deseas añadir al JSON principal.

Seguidamente recorres esos pares (los del objeto anidado), obteniendo la llave o clave de cada uno dinámicamente, es decir, sin importar el número de pares ni como se llaman sus claves. Con la llave iremos añadiendo el par clave valor al JSON principal.

Finalmente puedes eliminar el contenido anidado.

> Editado

Si encapsulas estos pasos en una función podrías añadir dinámicamente a un nivel superior cualquier contenido anidado indicando su clave:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        const jsonObj = {"content": [
            {
                "id": {
                    "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                    "idCliente": 830065063
                },
                "fechas": "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
                "planes": "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
                "correo": "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
                "enviado": true,
                "pdf": true,
                "excel": true
            }
        ]};

        // Imprimir en consola el JSON original
        console.log(jsonObj.content[0]);

        jsonObj.content[0]
            = upJsonContent(jsonObj.content[0], 'id', true);

        // Imprimir JSON resultante
        console.log(jsonObj.content[0]);



        function upJsonContent(json, nestedKey, removeNestedContent = false) // json
        {
            const jsonData = json[nestedKey];
            Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function(key) {
                json[key] = json[nestedKey][key];
            });

            if (removeNestedContent) {
                delete json[nestedKey];
            }

            return json;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero ***cuidado*** porque si el nivel superior ya tiene una clave que se corresponde con una del anidado se va a reescribir su valor si no añadimos lógica adicional.

Answer (score -1):

¿Cómo te va?

Hasta donde yo sé, no existe una manera automática o una función para hacer eso, sin embargo si sabes exactamente lo que tu JSON contiene, puedes reconstruirlo a tu gusto usando una clase:

```js
// Este es tu JSON, simplemente lo asigné a una variable "content"
let content = [
        {
            id: {
                "fechaSolicitud": "2021-10-09T06:42:45.163",
                "idCliente": 830065063
            },
            fechas: "[2021-07-31, 2021-06-30, 2021-05-31, 2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28]",
            planes: "[{f:25,p:110200908380}]",
            correo: "JOHNERWIN.HENAO@LGE.COM",
            enviado: true,
            pdf: true,
            excel: true
        }

]


// Esta sería la clase con la que vas a crear el objeto
class Content {
      constructor(fechaSolicitud, idCliente, fechas, planes, correo, enviado, pdf, excel) {
        this.fechaSolicitud = fechaSolicitud;
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
        this.fechas = fechas;
        this.planes = planes;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.enviado = enviado;
        this.pdf = pdf;
        this.excel = excel
      }
}
      
// Y aquí lo que estás haciendo es crear una nueva variable para guardar el resultado de crear un "nuevo" Content. Básicamente estás usando los datos que ya tienes en tu JSON, pero los estás usando para construir un nuevo objeto.
      let newContent = new Content(content[0].id.fechaSolicitud, content[0].id.idCliente, content[0].fechas, content[0].planes, content[0].correo, content[0].enviado, content[0].pdf, content[0].excel)
      

//Obtienes el resultado deseado
console.log(newContent)
```

Es posible que exista alguna otra solución más rápida, pero entendiendo el concepto de [Class](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp) vas a poder volver a manejar tu JSON rápidamente en el futuro cuando lo vuelvas a necesitar. Saludos!